# Simple regex invert not returning the full word

Tags: regex

I have very simple regex code :

```
(project-(?!old|rejected))
```

I have list of string like  :

```
project-ok 2016/3/4 
project-new 2016/4/5
project-in-progress 2015/3/8
project-cancel 2014/2/7
project-rejected 2011/9/2
... etc.
```

I want to capture project-anything except project-old and project-rejected.

When trying to match the line : **project-ok 2016/3/4**. I want it to return the  word   **'project-ok'** but I got return value : **'project-'** only.

How to match the full word of project's label ?

Comment: [`(project-(?!old|rejected)\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/sC7iV6/1)

Comment: @Tushar : Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what you are trying to do with `(project-(?!old|rejected))`

- `project-` matches `project-`.
- `(?!old|rejected)` looks ahead and checks if `old` or `rejected` is present. If YES then don't match. But nothing to do after it's **not present**

So you need to match the label until a whitespace is spotted. This can be done by using `\S+` or `[^\s]+` after your previous condition.

Complete regex would look like this: `project-(?!old|rejected)[^\s]+`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJ5jN8/1)**

Answer (score 1):

try with

> `project-(?!old\s|rejected\s)[-a-z]+`

https://regex101.com/r/wX2eY8/3

Comment: Maybe explain why this is working better.  The negative lookahead by itself only governs what branches the regex engine may not take when matching the following text.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
(?i)(project-(?!old|rejected)\b[-0-9a-z/ ]+)
```

And here goes the anatomy of the same:

```
(?i)                 # Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i)
(                    # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   project-             # Match the characters “project-” literally
   (?!                  # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
                           # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         old                  # Match the characters “old” literally
      |                    # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
         rejected             # Match the characters “rejected” literally
   )
   \\b                   # Assert position at a word boundary
   [-0-9a-z/ ]          # Match a single character present in the list below
                           # The character “-”
                           # A character in the range between “0” and “9”
                           # A character in the range between “a” and “z”
                           # One of the characters “/ ”
      +                    # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Hope this helps.